# How do i get a QT validator to work correctly when pasting text?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qvalidator

I have a QT `QRegExpValidator` (`RegExpValidator` in QML) which restricts my text input to alphanumeric content only.

However, when users paste strings into my `TextField` sometimes these strings end in a newline character, which fails validation, and so the string never gets pasted.

I have read that implementing the `fixup` method gives you a chance to clean up the strings so they work properly with the validator. However, this does not appear to work when pasting - the strings still do not get pasted.

How do i get this to work the way i want?

My code looks as follows:

```
LoginValidator { id: alphaNumValidator; regExp: /(?:[0-9A-Za-z])+$/ }
```

And the `LoginValidator` implementation is as follows:

```
class LoginValidator : public QRegExpValidator
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    virtual void fixup(QString &input) const override
    {
        input = input.simplified().remove(' ');
    }
};
```

Comment: @eyllanescisn't that exactly what i am using? i don't see the difference between your regex and mine 

Comment: @eyllanesc hmm, doesn't appear to be a typo, it works just fine...it's just a raw regex, which `regExp` accepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `fixup` method doesn't get called in the `validate` method of a `QRegExpValidator`. To get this working, I had to reimplement the `validate` method and call the fixup method there before calling the parent `validate` method.

```
QValidator::State LoginValidator::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
  fixup(input);
  return QRegExpValidator::validate(input, pos);
}
```

Comment: Dude you're a GENIUS! Thanks!

Comment: Nice workaround, but that shouldn't be needed at all. Please submit a bug report against whatever widget/QQ2 component you're using for inputting text.